# AppleScript: remove last character in text string

Tags: applescript

I need to remove the last character in a text string AppleScript. It's proving to the much more difficult problem than  I thought.
 can someone explain how this would be done?

Comment: Do you have a script so far that gets your text string?  If so, edit your question to show your current script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
set t to "this is a string"
text 1 thru -2 of t
```

Output:

"this is a strin"

Answer (score 6):

Sympathies. It ought to be a trivial task (in most languages it's just a matter of calling a built-in "trim" function) but AppleScript has absolutely miserable library support and the community has done nothing to plug these gaps itself, so you have to roll your own ad-hoc handlers for even basic everyday stuff like this. For example:

```
on trimLastChar(theText)
    if length of theText = 0 then
        error "Can't trim empty text." number -1728
    else if length of theText = 1 then
        return ""
    else
        return text 1 thru -2 of theText
    end if
end trimLastChar
```

You might consider investing in an [AppleScript book](http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=field-keywords=AppleScript) (note: I co-wrote the Apress one), which tend to cover common text and list processing tasks much better than AppleScript's own documentation.

Another option is to call through to Cocoa via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge, giving you free access to a huge amount of ready-to-use functionality. It's a bit more work, but for more advanced text processing tasks it's often the simplest, safest, and most efficient solution. I recommend getting a copy of Shane Stanley's [Everyday AppleScript-ObjC](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/everyday_book.html) if/when you go that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxnD5AViu6k#t=152.07430805"
    delay 1
end tell
delay 1

tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of front document as text
end tell

repeat while theURL contains "#"
    set theURL to text 1 thru -2 of theURL
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be interesting http://applehelpwriter.com/2016/09/06/applescript-remove-characters-from-a-string/

Essentially, you can import `Foundation` to help you

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString
```

Here is how I remove the last path component

```
on myRemoveLastPath(myPath)
  set myString to NSString's stringWithString:myPath
  set removedLastPathString to myString's stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
  removedLastPathString as text
end myRemoveLastPath
```